# all websites on webservers at 100%

Tags: asp.net, iis, vmware, cpu-usage, windows-server-2008-r2

So we have VM environment using VMWare consisting of 5 servers. 
Database server,

- Database Server
- File Server (all site content is on here)
- 3 Webservers in a load balancing configuration

Other notes:

- Application website uses .NET 3.5
- Webservers running windows server 2008 R2 Standard with IIS 7.5
- Each Virtual webserver is running Xeon 2680 with 4 cores and 16gb ram
- Database server is fine

There are around 30 websites on each webserver which is directed by a physical load balancer via round robin.

Each seperate website has a virtual directory called SharedContent which is outside the main website folder - on a separate content server.

that folder is shared and mapped as a virtual folder for all the websites

So all websites pull images, trailers from that same folder.
Currently there is around 1400000 files in the root folder and couple thousand in 7 sub folders in the shared content folder.

The issue is that on several occasions all webservers goes to 100% CPU and cause all websites to not respond as more requests are coming through. The application is based on ASP.NET 3.5, the servers starts returning 503

the websites are configured to use ASP.NET File based Caching

We have suspected it to be something to do with the SharedContent folder and all the files in it. We did a test of moving around 30 files to the shared folder (mapped as virtual directory in all sites) manually - at first the File Server peaked to 100% CPU (probably re-indexing the files) then this effect cascaded to all 3 webservers, all webservers hit 100% CPU and stayed there

The only way to bring the webservers back to functional is killing processes with high cpu usage from the resource manager.

we don't know why this happens - we are working on a patch to distribute files in that folder which will eventually create sub-folders and move files in there

what we don't know is what's the reason behind it ? - if we add a few files (copying 20-30 files) to that folder quickly, the CPU first shoots up on the file content server, then one by one all web servers also shoot upto 100% CPU usage

during these outages:

- traffic was normal
- operations were normal - no huge files suddenly being added to that folder

if anyone has any idea why this happens ? or reason behind this ?

Have anyone experienced anything like this before?

**Update: 20/1/17**

All websites have its own app pool on each webserver.

The only errors that were added in the event viewer at that time were Request timeouts.

The infrastructure was migrated from physical environment to VMs last August and never had an issue.

End of November 2016, 3 websites were upgraded to .net 4.5 which the rest was still on .net 3.5.
First instance of this issue happened at the end of December.

We attempted to add another permission role to the SharedContent folder which shoot it up to 100% CPU at peak period. We had to cancel the operation.

Traffic was normal.

SharedContent is configured as a mapped drive.

Comment: You got a memory leak somewhere in the app.

Comment: Is it one particular worker process that hits the 100% CPU? Also while technically possible I have seen issues when stored large amounts of files in a single folder, is it possible to breakdown the 1.4M files into different folders. Also I can imagine as all content is coming from 1 content server this could be placing a lot of stress on that box and the "network" between the content boxes and the web servers themselves?

Comment: It happens on all website processes. It seems to cascade to all 3 webservers and causes all of them to hit 100%. Yes. all content is stored on the file server and webservers just map to it. The Sharedcontent folder is outside the main websites folder. What i don't understand is how it cascades to all 3 webservers? The internal link between VMs is 1gigabit.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things I would check;

Have all websites got their own app pool, or is it shared between all 30 site on each server.

Have you isolated the exact process that is utilising 100%?

Do any errors get added to the event viewer?

Are you receiving any spikes in external traffic / internal traffic.

Are any error being generated on the vm host?

Are physical cpus being over allocated to vms?

Are the machines in a domain controller? Is that triggering any kind of update activity on the boxes?

How is the shared content done, mapped drive or MS distributed file system? If using DFS what topology is it?

Comment: Added additional info in the original post